# UIBarButtonItem not flat on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

just a quick question. I'm updating my company's app for iOS 7 and I'm running into  a couple of walls. Right now, the big one is the UIBarButtonItem. When I compile my app against iOS 7 then run the app, I get the old bar buttons.

In short, my bar button looks like this:

[image]

Instead of just the text. The application itself was originally coded on iOS 5 so we have been updating it for the last couple of years. Btw, here's how I'm adding the button:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
```

Any suggestions or leads will be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using a different Style

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... unfortunately, changing just the style has no effect on the button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That doesn't look like a system button.

Are you sure you are not setting a custom background to the button, maybe using the `UIAppearance` proxy?

Comment: Oh my god ... I had no idea about using a proxy objects to adjust UI elements. I just ran a search in Xcode and lo and behold, I found the code in the app delegate. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

maybe your have an image like background of your button'

Answer (score 3):

Try this :)

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: Dude...it's 2013...time to start using ARC!